# Intersecting 2 timeseries in SQL vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare the feasibility of doing "time series intersection" in SQL vs on my JavaScript frontend.

Let's say that I in both cases have this starting point:

```
//TimeSeries X
id, year, value
A, 2014, 5
B, 2014, 6

//TimeSeries Y
id, year, value
B, 2014, 334
```

To scatterplot this, I need to build a new table that has both x & y values for each entity and year. In this case the resulting table would only have 1 row.

```
id, year, x, y
B, 2014, 6, 334
```

**1) What would be the SQL syntax for achieving this?**

**2) What would be a JavaScript equivalent, for example using Lodash?**

Answer (score 0):

It should be performed using a simple join

```
Select table1.year, table1.value as x, table2.value as y from table1 join table2 on table1.year=table2.year;
```

I don't recommend a javascript implementation. Javascript shouldn't be used for long running operations especially server-side.

But to my eyes, the prefered way to implement it in javascript can be:

```
function intersection(xs, ys) {
    xs.sort((e1, e2) => e1.year - e2.year);
    ys.sort((e1, e2) => e1.year - e2.year);
    let output = []
    /*
     Notice that this function has side effects as it removes elements from the input arrays
     if you want to preserve the input arrays, try cloning them instead
     */
    while (xs.length > 0 && ys.length > 0) {
        if (xs[0].year == ys[0].year) {
            // if the two first elements have matching years, add element to output
            // notice the use of shift which remove the elements from the beginning of the arrays
            output.push({year: xs[0].year, x: xs.shift().value, y: ys.shift().value})
        } else if (xs[0].year < ys[0].year) {
            // if xs' year is smaller, peel the x
            xs.splice(0, 1);
        } else {
            // else peel the y value
            ys.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the SQL example join on both year and id? And for the JavaScript example, what if the first element is not the same year after the sort? Is this really robust if x has 2013,2014,2015,2016 and y has 2011, 2013?

Comment: Let's take your example: x has 2013,2014,2015,2016 and y has 2011, 2013. What would happen is:
1. 2011 is peeld off y
2. 2013 is peeled off x and y
3. it terminates since y became empty